# How to save a csv file so iPython shell can open and use it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, ipython

I'm a newbie to Python. I'm having trouble opening my csv file in the iPython shell, although I can open my file in Spyder just find. How can I save a csv, or any other file, properly to be used by both Spyder and iPython?

For example, I tried opening up and reading a file

```
DATA_data = open('Data.csv')

DATA_reader = (pd.read_csv(Data), ',')

print DATA_reader
```

and I would get this error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Data.csv'
```

Also, how can I make sure that the csv file is in the same director as my python script?

Comment: Please, edit you question to include what you have tried.

Comment: if you are using pandas, put that tag in your question, or some other package

Comment: Have you made sure that the file Data.csv is on the exact same directory as the python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `csv` file is plain text, so almost any code can read it.  With `ipython` you can read it with shell command, with Python read, or with numpy or pandas.

The first issue knowing where the file is located.  That's a file system issue - what's directory.  In `ipython` you can use the `%pwd` magic to see the current directory, and `%cd` to change directories.  `%ls` gives the directory listing.  With `magics` you can all the file and directory manipulation that you could with a linux shell like `bash` (and windows with some terminology adjustment).

Once you've located the file you can look at with `%cat`

For example:

```
In [26]: %pwd
Out[26]: '/home/paul'
In [27]: %ls
~/    Desktop/    Downloads/  mypy/      Public/     Videos/
bin/  Documents/  Music/      Pictures/  Templates/
In [28]: %cd mypy
/home/paul/mypy
In [29]: %ls test*
test       test2.hdf  test.h5    test.ipy    test.mat  test.npz
test1.hdf  test.gz    test.hdf5  testipy.py  test.npy  test.txt
In [30]: %cat test
       one          a          1
       two          b          2
     three          c          3
```

Plain Python read:

```
In [34]: f=open('test')
In [35]: f.read()
Out[35]: '       one          a          1\n       two          b          2\n     three          c          3\n'
In [36]: f.close()
```

`np.genfromtxt` is the most powerful `numpy` csv reader:

```
In [38]: np.genfromtxt('test',dtype=None)
Out[38]: 
array([(b'one', b'a', 1), (b'two', b'b', 2), (b'three', b'c', 3)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', 'S1'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

In this case I got a 1d array with a structured dtype - because of the mix of string and numeric columns.  My delimiter in this case is white space.

or `loadtxt`:

```
In [40]: np.loadtxt('test',dtype='str')
Out[40]: 
array([["b'one'", "b'a'", "b'1'"],
       ["b'two'", "b'b'", "b'2'"],
       ["b'three'", "b'c'", "b'3'"]], 
      dtype='<U8')
```

I don't have `pandas` installed on this machine so can't demonstrate that, though I think `data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',')` should be sufficient (ie. file name and delimiter).